# Term for an event where you present on a topic/research for general knowledge sharing

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

My synapses are failing to fire, but I need help finding a word for an event/gathering where a topic or research is presented, usually to peers for general knowledge sharing and/or discussion.

We used to do them in college, for example about interesting ways to use analytical geometry in everyday life. I feel like the word was Latin in etymology, but that doesn't really narrow it down. I tried finding similar events on Google but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply presentation, or paper presentation? Feel free to write an answer with this, anyone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Cambridge:

> **[symposium](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/symposium)**
>
> noun [ C ] UK ​ /sɪmˈpəʊ.zi.əm/ US ​ /sɪmˈpoʊ.zi.əm/ plural symposia symposiums formal
>
> an occasion at which people who have great knowledge of a particular subject meet in order to discuss a matter of interest:
>
> *a symposium on European cinema*

Or:

> **[colloquium](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/colloquium)**
>
> noun [ C ] UK ​ /kəˈləʊkwiəm/ US ​ formal MEETINGS
>
> a meeting in which a lot of people discuss something formally:
>
> *colloquium on sth
>
> She attended a colloquium on climate change in Greenland.*

Comment: you're the best! I had assumed symposium was just for music, good to know! We had called it a colloquium! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Davo's symposium, but if you'd like more options:

[con·ven·tion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/convention)

> a meeting or formal assembly, as of representatives or delegates, for discussion of and action on particular matters of common concern

[con·fer·ence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdvIDWxcXVAhXHr1QKHVfaC7wQFghRMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fconference&usg=AFQjCNF7Xn4vJCn4jXq_s5vRswaDDRuPBw)

> a formal meeting that typically takes place over a number of days and involves people with a shared interest, especially one held regularly by an association or organization

[sem·i·nar](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirvYPsxcXVAhXIw1QKHaerC9YQFghHMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fseminar&usg=AFQjCNF66zpE4FTOxOjLo9RIDhm2wCmJbA)

> a conference or other meeting for discussion or training

[work·shop](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzn9z9xcXVAhVnwlQKHaPVC5EQFghCMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fworkshop&usg=AFQjCNHpLRqfQhn3yfg21S2fPcgyTdj48Q)

> a meeting at which a group of people engage in intensive discussion and activity on a particular subject or project